# Java: ArrayList: Determine if entry exists by its index

Tags: java, arrays

How can I check if value exist in ArrayList by its index?

Java offers contains(Object) method, but no contains(Integer index) method

Thank you

Comment: How does this relate to Sharepoint?

Comment: don't know how that tag got there, removed it now, thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not at all sure what your question is. You talk about seeing if an entry "exists" but then you talk about Java lacking a `remove(Object index)` method.

Regarding remove: There's the [remove(int)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#remove(int)) method on the `List` interface implemented by `ArrayList`. (Java `List`s are indexed by `int`, not by `Object`.)

Regarding whether an entry "exists" at a given index, if the list's `size()` method is greater than the index (and the index is non-negative), then there's an entry at that index:

```
if (index >= 0 && index < list.size()) {
    // An entry exists; hey, let's remove it
    list.remove(index);
}
```

Comment: Thanks.
the post was messy because I've accidently confused "remove" and "contains"

Comment: FFR, the Java Doc specifies when you would receive and IndexOutOfBoundsException, so reversing this logic would give you valid indexes.

Comment: Simple and Amazing Solution, worked like a warm! Thanks and upvoted

Answer (score 3):

If you have a sparse array (which can contain null values) you might want to check for this as well.

```
public static boolean isSet(List<?> list, int index) {
   return index >=0 && index < list.size() && list.get(index) != null;
}
```

Not sure why you would want the index to be Integer type but if you do you should check for null as well. Allowing a null value is the only good reason to have an Integer type.

```
public static boolean isSet(List<?> list, Integer index) {
   return index != null && index >=0 && index < list.size() && list.get(index) != null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> How can I check if value exist in ArrayList by its index?

Try this:

```
int     aIndex = ...;
boolean aIsExistByIndex = (aIndex >= 0) && (aIndex < AL.size())
```

Hope this help :-p

Comment: I don't see why this answer was voted *down*; the proposed expression is correct. It just lacks amplifying explanation.

Comment: Thank you, I used your code. 
I don't know who voted it down, but I think it was voted down because at first it missed part of the code (probably posted accidently forgot to finish it)

Comment: It was likely partly my fault as I initially forgot the escape '>' and '<' :-p.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should consider using a HashMap instead of an ArrayList. 
There is a reason why the method exist(int index) is not implemented for ArrayList (mainly because it takes to much memory to implement an ArrayList for specifics indexes):

```
int i = 3; int j = 4;
HashMap<Integer, Integer> hm = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
hm.put(3, 4);
hm.containsKey(3);
```